# Angular Unit Test shows error warnings of kind NG0304 "component is not a known element" even after the component stubs have been declared

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I am writing unit tests for an Angular component that uses multiple child components which are used with @ViewChild({}) in the following way:

Template:

```html
...
<app-app-form></app-app-form>
<app-terms-form></app-terms-form>
...
```

Model:

```js
...
@ViewChild(AppFormComponent, {static: true}) protected appForm: AppFormComponent;
@ViewChild(TermsFormComponent, {static: true}) protected termsForm: TermsFormComponent;
...
```

In total I use six such components. For testing purposes I declared component stubs in this way:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-terms-form',
  template: '',
  providers: [
    { provide: TermsFormComponent, useClass: TermsFormStubComponent }
  ]
})
class TermsFormStubComponent implements Partial<IFormComp<any>> {
...
}
```

When I run my tests I get error warning messages for all used child components although I declared them in the TestBed:

```
ERROR: 'NG0304: 'app-terms-form' is not a known element (used in the 'CreateLicenseComponent' component template):
1. If 'app-terms-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
```

I want my tests to not display any error warnings for things that I deem already fixed but I can not figure out how to stop it. The TestBed is configured with all the necessary components.

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    ...
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ... ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ], // doesn't resolve the error warnings NG0304
      declarations: [
        CreateLicenseComponent,
        OrderFormStubComponent,
        DeviceFormStubComponent,
        AppFormStubComponent,
        TermsFormStubComponent,
        DnFormStubComponent,
        ExpiresFormStubComponent
      ],
      providers: [ ... ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateLicenseComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

As you can see I already added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, also tried each individually. But it doesn't work. And I should not have to add them in the first place because all needed elements are in the "declarations" array. I still get the error warnings for all six child components

My tests run all successfully and through debugging I already confirmed that the component stubs are available. I could just ignore these error warnings but they are nevertheless annoying in particular because I am going to add more components like the showcased one. Does anyone have an idea how to cleanly solve this problem?